# How to make and add a MediaStreamTrack to a media stream

Tags: javascript, mediastream

I am wondering how to make and add a MediaStreamTrack to a MediaStream. I cant find a way to add or make one, and so I'm stuck. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1: Generate the tracks.**

```js
const userMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio : true, video : true});

const videoTrack = userMedia.getVideoTracks()[0];
const audioTrack = userMedia.getAudioTracks()[0];
```

**Step 2: Create a MediaStream and add tracks to them.**

```js
const stream = new MediaStream();
stream.addTrack(videoTrack);
stream.addTrack(audioTrack);
```

Now you can use that MediaStream as whatever you want.

**To render the stream in HTML, create a video element in your HTML and set it's id to "localVideo" (It's optional, set it whatever you want.
To attach stream to that video element, use:**

```js
const videoElement = document.getElementById("localVideo");
videoElement.srcObject = userMedia;
videoElement.play();
```

*Note : navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia also returns a MediaStream. So there is no difference about the mentality between Step 1 and Step 2.*

**Important Note :** If you set "muted" prop to false of video element, you can't autoplay it in most of cases. If you want to autoplay the video without any user interaction to window, you have to set muted true.

If you want to get screen recording track, use:

```js
const screenMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i run the second snippet after the first, it says this: VM1789:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: videoTrack is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:17 
EDIT: it works now.

Comment: Would you know how to show and play the audio and the video in html? and how to record my screen?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. Now edited the answer.

Comment: As well as computer audio.

Comment: Just create a video element in HTML and set it's srcObject to userMedia.

Comment: Does 'const screenMedia = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
' work for sound too?

Comment: Also, how could i make it so that when a button is clicked, the stream starts?

Comment: It depends on your JavaScript code. Collect all those operations in functions or a single function. Then execute that function when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer solves the problem. But devices (camera or mic) still will be used even if you don't add them to the stream. Camera activity led, if there is a one, will be lit, which is something suspicious for users.

You can create a new stream by calling getUserMedia(). This solution could be something you are already aware, but this method is cleaner imo.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({...audioConfig,...videoConfig})
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(audioConfig)
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoConfig})
```